# How can I change the permission of my sdcard permission

Tags: android, permissions, adb, sd-card, mount

I have a Android phone connected to my Linux's usb port. But I cannot access its **sdcard**
directory in adb shell. I tried rebooting, reinserting the device, but it never worked. Besides, it's strange that I don't have **su** or **sudo** in my adb shell, so I am prohibited from doing

> sudo mount -o remount rw ...

as well. Any workaround?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: adb remount -- used to work, but it was a good while ago. That is, since some version number you may have to use a dev build for it to work.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia, I am developing an Android application. It always fails to find external directories. Logging onto adb shell led me to find the /mnt/sdcard cannot be read nor entered

Comment: please provide output of `echo $SECONDARY_STORAGE` and `vdc volume list`

Comment: shell@android:/ $ echo $SECONDARY_STORAGE

shell@android:/ $ vdc volume list
110 0 external_sd /storage/sdcard0 7
110 0 internal_sd /storage/sdcard1 7
200 0 Volumes listed.
shell@android:/ $

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this in a hardware device (not emulated) you will need to root your Phone to change the permission of the folders.

See this link: http://www.androidcentral.com/root

Or this (Framaroot): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2130276

Hope it helps

Comment: doesn't seem easy to root my HuaWei G525 phone. Its bootloader is encrypted. Anyworkaround, since previously I can normally use my sdcard dir but somehow all of sudden, it went wild, and I can no longer enter it anymore